# Flex sensor aren't reacted. arduino

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm trying controlling the 5 servo snd Flex sensor. So, I connect the Arduino with Bled Board(Flex sensor and 5 servo).

However, though I bended these Flex sensors, they are not reacted.

that code is below.

```
//  letsarduino.com
//  [Project 15] - 5 Flex/Bend Sensor + 5 Servo Motor + Arduino
#include <Servo.h>     

Servo servoMotor1;      
Servo servoMotor2;
Servo servoMotor3;
Servo servoMotor4;
Servo servoMotor5;

int servoPin1 = 2;      
int servoPin2 = 3; 
int servoPin3 = 4; 
int servoPin4 = 5; 
int servoPin5 = 6; 

void setup() {

  servoMotor1.attach(servoPin1);  
  servoMotor2.attach(servoPin2);
  servoMotor3.attach(servoPin3);
  servoMotor4.attach(servoPin4);
  servoMotor5.attach(servoPin5);

} 

void loop()
{

  int analogValue = analogRead(A0); 
  int servoAngle = map(analogValue, 550, 640, 0, 179);
  servoMotor1.write(servoAngle);

  int analogValue2 = analogRead(A1); 
  int servoAngle2 = map(analogValue2, 550, 640, 0, 179);
  servoMotor2.write(servoAngle2);

  int analogValue3 = analogRead(A2); 
  int servoAngle3 = map(analogValue3, 550, 640, 0, 179);
  servoMotor3.write(servoAngle3);

  int analogValue4 = analogRead(A3); 
  int servoAngle4 = map(analogValue4, 550, 640, 0, 179);
  servoMotor4.write(servoAngle4);

  int analogValue5 = analogRead(A4); 
  int servoAngle5 = map(analogValue5, 550, 640, 0, 179);
  servoMotor5.write(servoAngle5);

}
```

Do you know why these flex sensors and servo motors are not reacted?
I think Wiring between bred board and arduino, flex sensors and servo motors are not mistaken.

Comment: I referred to  the connection between arduino and bred board, servo and flex sensors from 

http://www.letsarduino.com/project-15-5-flexbend-sensor-5-servo-motor-arduino/

Comment: And I used the Aruduino UNO.